# Why isn't this zero search result triggering the No-Results found dialog?

Tags: bixby

This search produces zero results as you can see in the response body, but it is not triggering the zero results default dialog.  I assume this means that if you create a custom results view, you must account for all possible scenarios of size = x?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may require a deeper look at your capsule code since I am able to see a default "I couldn't find any [Concept]" without any issues.

[image: Debug panel plan]

[image: Simulator result]

I would recommend reaching out to the support team via the Contact Support option in the Help dropdown menu of Bixby Developer Studio so the team can look through your capsule code.